# Renaming symbolic links in a shell scripts

Tags: bash, symlink

Lets say I have 3 symbolic links (pointing to different deployment version files).

```
A -> K
B -> L
C -> M
```

When I do a new deploy (called H), I would like the end result to look like:

```
A -> H
B -> K
C -> L
```

The only information that I have are the names of A, B, and C, and the name of H. The names of K, L, M are unknown me but could be found by following the symbolic links.

How would I make a script in bash shell that does that for me?

(Note: A, B, C are the symbolic links created using `ln -s`)

Comment: You'll want the [`readlink`](http://man.cx/readlink) tool

Comment: Thanks, I think that should get me most of the way there. Never heard that command before.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you would need to know the old file name..unless you need to delete it. I wrote this real quickly and it seems to work fine. It doesn't need the old released file name.

```
!/bin/bash
remove_old()
    {
            rm -f "$1"
    }
make_new()
    {
            ln -s "$1" "$2"
    }

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
    {
        echo "Nope, you need to provide..."
        echo "(1) link/file name to be removed."
        echo "(2) link/file name to be created"
        echo "(3) the actual file location for #2"      
    }   
    elif [ ! -f "${3}" ]; then
    {
        echo "Sorry, your target ${3} doesn’t exist or is not accessible"
    }
    elif [ -f ${2} ]; then
    {
        echo "Sorry, the new file already exists...want me to remove it?"
        read remove
        if [ "$remove" = "Y" ]||[ "$remove" = "y"]; then
            {
                rm -f "$2"
                remove_old $1
                make_new    $3 $2   
            }
            else
            {
                exit
            }
        fi               
    }
    else
    {
        remove_old $1
        make_new $3 $2
    }
    fi
```

And here is the debugged output...

```
bash -xv autolinker.sh my_link my_new_link test_2/test_file 
#!/bin/bash
remove_old()
    {
            rm -f "$1"
    }
make_new()
    {
            ln -s "$1" "$2"
    }

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
    {
        echo "Nope, you need to provide..."
        echo "(1) link/file name to be removed."
        echo "(2) link/file name to be created"
        echo "(3) the actual file location for #2"      
    }   
    elif [ ! -f "${3}" ]; then
    {
        echo "Sorry, your target ${3} doesn’t exist or is not accessible"
    }
    elif [ -f ${2} ]; then
    {
        echo "Sorry, the new file already exists...want me to remove it?"
        read remove
        if [ "$remove" = "Y" ]||[ "$remove" = "y"]; then
            {
                rm -f "$2"
                remove_old $1
                make_new    $3 $2   
            }
            else
            {
                exit
            }
        fi               
    }
    else
    {
        remove_old $1
        make_new $3 $2
    }
    fi
+ '[' 3 -ne 3 ']'
+ '[' '!' -f test_2/test_file ']'
+ '[' -f my_new_link ']'
+ echo 'Sorry, the new file already exists...want me to remove it?'
Sorry, the new file already exists...want me to remove it?
+ read remove
Y
+ '[' Y = Y ']'
+ rm -f my_new_link
+ remove_old my_link
+ rm -f my_link
+ make_new test_2/test_file my_new_link
+ ln -s test_2/test_file my_new_link
```